# Jquery Ajax não funcionando devidamente em Browser Mobile bem como em MacOS

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, navegador-de-internet

O Seguinte código funciona perfeitamente no Browser do Windows 10, mas não funciona no browser mobile Android/IOS completamente e no MacOS dá uma menssagem dizendo ao usuário de que não está funcionando bem. O problema parece estar em: `success: function(result)`.

O resto do código funciona, a única coisa é que nao funciona é div $('#aviso'), por isso testei em partes isoladas. Quando executado em partes funciona, mas está dentro do código completo não.

```
$(function () {

    $("form[name='form-inscricao']").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:'https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/example.com/enviar.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: serializedData,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loader').show();
                $('#aviso').text('');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Something went wrong');
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('#aviso').append(result).css({opacity:1.0}).delay(1000).animate({opacity : 0},500);
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('.loader').hide();
                $form.get(0).reset();
                $inputs.prop("disabled", false);

            }});

        });
});
```

Comment: Aqui é StackOverflow em Português, por favor, traduza sua pergunta, ou mova para o StackOverflow em Inglês.

Comment: Você editou a pergunta para que esteja em português, mas agora o problema não está claro. Defina "não funcionar".

Comment: Pode ser outros plugins ou scripts antes deste, dê detalhes por favor.

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava relacionado ao protocolo HTTPS na URL, por alguma razão o Browser Mobile é redirecionado para a URL http sem o SSL enquanto o navegador não. 
Desta forma o ajax não conseguia retornar a requisição para a URL correta. Tudo o que eu fiz foi deletar a parte da URL que incluia o http e deixar somente à partir da pasta raiz.

Obs: Este problema esta mais suscetível a acontecer quando se utiliza um framework PHP como o WordPress e não se escreve corretamente os Links e URLS do site, especialmente em scripts js como esse.

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'/wp-content/themes/example.com/enviar.php',
```